# How to remove data from Many2many field via custom method in wizard in odoo 10?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have two views :
1. Registration form view
2  Update Registration Wizard view.
Models :
1 Registration
2  Members

I am setting up a registration process with Many2many fields ('members').
After registration process, a Button (Update Members) showing on Form view.
When clicking this button appears a wizard window where registered members are showing. 
Here i need to delete some members ( from listed members on wizard) and click on ApplyChanges button for changes (calling custom function - ApplyChanges). And atlast changes will be applied on main Registrations model.how can i do this??

```
incoming_member_ids = fields.Many2many("members", String='Incoming Members')
```

outgoing_member_ids = fields.Many2many("members", String='Outgoing Members')

```
### incoming members list
if x.action_type == 'incoming_members':
   for incoming_partner in x.incoming_members_ids:
      incoming_member_ids.append(incoming_member.id)
      if not incoming_member_ids:
        continue
      self.env['registered.members'].create({
     'member_ids': incoming_member_ids[0],
     })
     incoming_member_ids.remove(incoming_member_ids[0])
   return True
  ### Outgoing members list  
 elif x.action_type == 'outgoing_members':                   
    for outgoinging_member in res.outgoing_member_ids:
        outgoing_member_ids.append(outgoinging_member.id)
        if not outgoing_member_ids:
           continue
      self.env['registered.members'].create({
     'member_ids': outgoing_member_ids[0],
     })    
     outgoing_member_ids.remove(outgoing_member_ids[0])
   return True
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Mentioned above my tried code

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Check at https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html

Answer (score 0):

To remove relation of a particular id from a `man2many` field, you have to use `odoo` provided notation on the field. Let's suppose recordset you want perform operation on is `records`, man2many field is `outgoing_member_ids`, id you want to remove from that relation is `outgoing_member_ids[0]`, you have to write:

```
records.write({'outgoing_member_ids': [(3, outgoing_member_ids[0])]})
```

Comment: Actually i am having three models and one wizard model as i mentioned.
1  Registration
2. Members
3 .RegisteredMembers
4 . ActionWizard

ActionWizard Transient model having:
registered_member_ids = Many2many('registered.members')
outgoing_member_id = Many2many('registered.members')

i want to remove records of via outgoing_member_id of registered_member_id linked to registered.members model.